# PHP Warning: Invalid Foreach() argument supplied in IE

Tags: php

I am building a dependent dropdown list for a website. I have been able to build it and it works just fine. But, I get a **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** error message when I open the website in Internet Explorer.

For some reason, I don't get the error in Chrome and Firefox. I am sure this is not a browser problem and must be something to do with my PHP code.

I have tried the following but still get the error:

1. **Verify the variable is not null with isset**

   ```
   echo "<select name='subcat3' ><option value=''>Select one</option>";
   $abc = $dbo->query(@$quer3);
   if (isset($abc)) :
   foreach ($abc as $noticia) :
   echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcat2]'>$noticia[subcat2]</option>";
   endforeach;
   endif;
   echo "</select>";
   ```
2. **Verified if it is an array**

Verified if it is an array by using is_array. But using it ruins the dropdown functionality.

```
    if (is_array($abc)) :
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: this does not look like regular PHP. Have you tried the regular syntax to see if the effect is the same?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($abc);` for us?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $noticia['subcat2']???

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this is regular PHP just another way of writting it

Comment: @Mike - [Alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: I'd suggest dropping the VB-style syntax, even if PHP does allow it, because its just not readable. The error cannot be browser specific, however, because PHP runs on the server-side.

Comment: alternative syntax that is prone to confusing the author, hence the suggestion to rewrite to regular syntax: the mere exercise of rewriting it to normal syntax is likely to reveal an oddity or even problem with the code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans not true if the programmer that use the abnormal syntax is use to it then changing to another syntax than the one he/she is used to will cause more problem. But if you are worth half a programmer the syntax shouldn't bother you at all it is still PHP after all

Comment: But php isn't browser related its a server side language... it shouldn't be just IE crashing... Can you post the full error message? line number and everything?

Answer (score 0):

First:

$abc seems to be an array or at least seems to be a key/value structure so your for each loop should be:

```
foreach ($abc as $key=>$noticia):
```

Second:

Is $abc an multidimensionnal array/structure? else you dont need to add the `[subcat2]`.
If it is tought a multidimensionnal array you should refered to its key with quotation mark such as `$noticia['subcat2']`

Comment: It's not multidimensional. And this is called an Associative Array.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf sorry i speak french so I couldn't find the right word to translate 'une paire clé valeur.'

Comment: @Sebastien Sorry, this didn't help. I still get the error and it shows only in IE and not other browsers. Not sure why...

Comment: @akumarks I'll wait till you provide some more informations than will update my answer.